# Show dropdown-menu on hover and close on click using only CSS

Tags: html, css, pointer-events

Can someone help me with an explanation as to why the links from a dropdown menu are not working when I click on them? Maybe because of pointer events? I'm trying to have a dropdown menu that is closing after a link is clicked or the close button is clicked. I have added some cool stuff like hiding parent container when a link is clicked.

There are many options doing that:

1. using `:focus` but when the focus is used the drop-down will not be
   triggered on the next hover over dropdown.
2. using `:active` on container and `pointer-events` to point only the
   active links, but pointer events is buggy
3. using `:target` but has the same problem as :focus, will not trigger
   the second hoover.

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid lime;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
.test1 {
    display: none;
    border: 1px dashed orange;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.container:hover .test1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.container:hover .test1:active {
    display: none;
}
a {
    pointer-events: auto;
    color: lime;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  Drop down menu
 <li class="test1">
 <a class="dropdown" href="#">X Close</a>
 <ul class="content">
   CLOSE THIS CONTENT
  <li class="link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to link 1</a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 2</a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: @hungerstar nope, not working on Chrome. The right behaviour should be to redirect you into google page while clicking on links.

Comment: li and ul end tags are missing.

Comment: You' re saying that "trying to have a dropdown menu that is closing after a link is clicked". Will the links have `target="blank"`? Otherwise how would you know if the menu got closed since you'll be redirected to the link?

Comment: do you need `X Close` or it can be optional ? actually its like either of close button or links will work as hover effect is conflicting them.

Comment: @pradeep1991singh I need a close button because my original dropdown menu is actually very big so I need that there .

Comment: @RulerNature let me know if my answer suits your needs, Else if you want to achieve the functionality without changing your HTML even a bit.. let me know .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick Check : **[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/rxke3w15/2/)**

> Can someone help me with an explanation as to why the links from a dropdown menu are not working when I click on them? Maybe because of pointer events?

**Explanation on why this behavior**:
Yes you are right, It is because of the way you are using the `:active` selector logic, To explain in detail, consider your this CSS rule

```
.container:hover .test1:active {
    display: none;
}
```

You have your menu links under your main `li.test1` and any click on the inner links are also bubbled up to this element, so its as good as clicking the `li`. So as soon as the mouse is held down (mouse down event) it triggers the `:active` event and you are hiding the `links` (ie: `li.test1`), But a **click event is complete only when mouse is both down and up**. So by now the `li` is hidden and the `mouse up` is no longer on the link. So as you see there is no chance of the click event to be triggered. This is the issue.

---

`I saw other answers which you seem to be interested in and this really doesn't need any kind of hack, It can be done by just formatting your HTML and with some CSS changes.`

---

**Solution:** Rather than wrapping up your inner menu links inside the `li.test1` you can **work with two different `li`** , One for the `X CLose` and other for holding the `menu links`. With this in place we can make sure **when ever the `li.test1` is active** (ie mouse is down) we can **hide it and also the other new `li`** which is adjacent to it. So this means when ever the user clicks on the `X Close` `li` we  hide the menu, If he clicks on the other menu items you are redirected.

So the changes in your HTML structure should be like

```
<ul class="container">
  Drop down menu
  <li class="test1">
    <a class="dropdown" href="#">X Close</a>
  </li>
  <li class="MenuLinks">
    <ul class="content">
      <!-- all your links go here-->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And Main CSS rule is

```
.container:hover .test1:active,
.container:hover .test1:active + .MenuLinks {
  display: none;
}
```

Below is a SO working Snippet

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.test1,
.MenuLinks {  
  display: none;
  border-color: orange;
  border-style: dashed;
  background: green;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.test1 {
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
}
.MenuLinks {
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.container:hover li {
  display: block;
}

/*Rule to hide both test1 and MenuLinks when X Close is clicked*/
.container:hover .test1:active,
.container:hover .test1:active + .MenuLinks {
  display: none;
}


a {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: lime;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  Drop down menu
  <li class="test1">
    <a class="dropdown" href="#">X Close</a>
  </li>
  <!--seperate li for close-->

  <li class="MenuLinks">
    <!--wrap all your menu items here-->
    <ul class="content">
      CLOSE THIS CONTENT
      <li class="link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

---

*Note:* The blank screen when you click on the links are due to the google's security Restrictions on cross origin policy which gives this error in console

`Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=x2VWWLL2Ae-K8Qfwx4ngDQ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

However you can see the requests in the network tab when you click on the links.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @Rajshekar Reddy your answer is pretty good and keep the <ul> <li> structure which is very important, but when I click on links, nothing happen...should redirect to google page, I'm not sure why

Comment: @RulerNature see my reason on the *Note* section.. It is actually redirecting.. since the code is running in an iframe you see this error. Create your own HTML file and put this code.. You can see it redirecting to the specified link

Comment: @RulerNature here I added all the above code into a html file and uploaded here https://www.sendspace.com/file/j1kss3 . You can download this and see the desired behavior.  let me know if you need anything else

Comment: @Rajshekar Reddy thank you very much man, let me test a little bit your work and I'll let you know :)

Comment: @Rajshekar Reddy can you help me please to integrate that into a bootstrap drop-down ? here is a small fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28011/

Comment: @RulerNature here you go.. I changed the CSS selector to select all the siblings using `~` https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/DTcHh/28013/

Comment: @RulerNature another update to remove the small glitch during hiding the menu https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/DTcHh/28016/

Answer (score 4):

I would do this normally using JS - but with CSS there *is* a hack:

First create an input with id `close` and a `label` for this that wraps our close button:

```
  <input type="radio" id="close" />
  <li class="test1">
    <label for="close">
      <a class="dropdown" href="#">X Close</a>
    </label>
```

and add in this style instead of the current `.test1:active`:

```
.container:hover #close:active + .test1{
  display: none;
}
#close {
  display: none;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
.test1 {
  display: none;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.container:hover .test1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
#close {
  display: none;
}
.container:hover #close:active + .test1 {
  display: none;
}
a {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: lime;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  Drop down menu
  <input type="radio" id="close" />
  <li class="test1">
    <label for="close">
      <a class="dropdown" href="#">X Close</a>
    </label>
    <ul class="content">
      CLOSE THIS CONTENT
      <li class="link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But the above code has an invalid `input` element inside a `ul` - to prevent that you can edit the markup a bit to create one more wrapper for the `ul` (maybe you have to adjust the widths/padding a bit due to the markup change) - see code below:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul {
  width: 200px;
}
.test1 {
  display: none;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.container:hover .test1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
#close {
  display: none;
}
.container:hover #close:active + ul > li.test1 {
  display: none;
}
a {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: lime;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Drop down menu
  <input type="radio" id="close" />
  <ul>
    <li class="test1">
      <label for="close">
        <a class="dropdown" href="#">X Close</a>
      </label>
      <ul class="content">
        CLOSE THIS CONTENT
        <li class="link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: but the links are not redirecting you to the google page :|

Comment: that snippet won't worked but I have created a fiddle based on your code and yes, worked. Only one issue, the input is not allowed inside ul at that level :)

Comment: @RulerNature you are right, I totally missed that... See the edited answer with the corrected code using an extra wrapper in the markup...

Comment: The snippet can never work because redirects are blocked inside its iframe (not your fault, it's Stack overflow security)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to work because on mouse down the `:hover`-class for keeping the dropdown menu open is vanished. So the mouse up event is not executed on the link because the dropdown is already closed again, so no click is performed. You should use javascript to open and close the dropdown menu.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but why ? it is that normal ?

Comment: If you take away `.container:hover .test1:active {
    display: none;
}`it seems to work.

Comment: doing that the container will not be closed when click on close top button or links ...

Comment: Yeah CSS is not very powerful when it comes to interactivity, that's why I suggested to use Javascript, because it is either a very complex thing to do in CSS or not possible, but I can't proof whether it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing

```
.container:hover .test1:active {
    display: none;
}
```

and find another way (a few lines of javascript will do) to close the panel when you click on the "X Close" link. (Also fixed some html missing tags by the way). Now the links are working:

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid lime;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
.test1 {
    display: none;
    border: 1px dashed orange;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.container:hover .test1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
a {
    pointer-events: auto;
    color: lime;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  Drop down menu
  <li class="test1">
    <a class="dropdown" href="#">X Close</a>
    <ul class="content">
      CLOSE THIS CONTENT
      <li class="link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to link 1</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 2</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not an option, I need that active in order to close the container after the links are accessed or when the "close" button on top is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `label` and `button` in place on `a` for closing link and can do something like below -

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.test1 {
  display: none;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container:hover .test1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

a, label {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: lime;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* close button */
#xclose:active + .test1 {
  display:none;
}

#xclose {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  Drop down menu
  <button id="xclose">X close</button>
  <li class="test1">    
    <label class="dropdown" for="xclose">X Close</label>        
    <ul class="content">
      CLOSE THIS CONTENT
      <li class="link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to link 1</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 2</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this will help you in some way (y).

Answer (score 0):

Why did you add `"pointer-events: none;"` to the list-element .test1? This overwrites your `pointer-events: auto;`.Try to remove it, because it binds your click event.

Comment: need that pointer events there in order to close container only on links and not when you click on whole container . So with pointer-events can indicate to do that only on links ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try and use `jQuery` to handle closing the container only when a link is pressed. `pointer-events` have many issues. Because of this they have decided to postpone the feature to CSS4.

I also think `pointer-events: none;` prevents any click events to be fired, so using jQuery just for the link wont work. I think you'll have to fix the opening and closing of the container with jQuery.

Comment: with javascript that can be done in a minute but I don't want  to use js, it's possible doing that only with css, I saw something similar done with :target and :active but in my case I need to apply that behaviour to those links.

Comment: @RulerNature But what is the reason you don't want to use JS? Why spend so much time on trying to implement a CSS feature that they said will not be supported well till CSS4.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can bind `label` elements to `inputs`. Given this, you can bind the close button to an input that - when active - hides the list again.

```css
body{
  padding: 20px;
}

a, label{
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: lime;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container{
  border: 1px solid lime;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown{
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: green;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#close, #close:active + .dropdown{
  display: none;
}

.container:hover .dropdown{
  display: block;
}

.dropdown > ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Drop down menu
  <button id="close"></button>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <label for="close">X Close</label>
    <ul>
      <li class="link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to link 1</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 2</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `input` with `id="close"` is inserted before the list, and will be triggered by the label with `for="close"`
When it is triggered, the following rule will take effect:

```
#close, #close:active + .dropdown{
  display: none;
}
```

Which hides the list.
But when you hover over the `.container`, it will show up again, allowing you to repeat the process.
There is no need for unnecessary JavaScript here. An input will do.

There were also some things wrong with your code. You had the text `Drop down menu` and `CLOSE THIS CONTENT` directly inside an `ul`, which can not be done. An `ul` can only contain `li`'s, and nothing else.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
.container:hover .test1:active {
display: none;
}
```

Change this like to

```
.container:hover .test1:focus{
    display: none;
    }
```

What's happening here is that when your div is getting the "active" psuedo code from your link click, it's hiding before the DOM bubbles to your link to give the redirect. Changing it to focus might allow the click to actually go through?

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to use `animate`.I have given a example with your code with `opacity`. Using `visibility:hidden` or `overflow:hidden` will enhance your code.

```
    body {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .container {
        border: 1px solid lime;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .test1 {
        display: none;
        border: 1px dashed orange;
        background: green;
        padding: 10px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .container:hover .test1 {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    a {
        pointer-events: auto;
        color: lime;
        font-weight: bold;
    }


.container .test1 {
  -webkit-animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  position: relative;
}
@-webkit-keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;

  }

@keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;

  }
}
    <ul class="container">
      Drop down menu
     <li class="test1">
     <a class="dropdown" href="#">X Close</a>
     <ul class="content">
       CLOSE THIS CONTENT
      <li class="link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to link 1</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 2</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Go to link 3</a></li>
     </ul>
```